# I can not access the array that I attached to my pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I am using Many to Many relationships between `Students` and `Packages` which generate `student_package` pivot table. And I attached some extra variables, but I can not access them in my view.

Here is my code

## Controller

```
$student->packages()->attach($request->package_id, ['paid' => '1','transaction_id'=>$transaction_id, 'amount' => $request->amount]);
```

## View

```
@foreach ($student->packages as $package)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$package->id}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->amount}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->no_hours}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->transaction_id}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->paid}} </td>
                                                    
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I can't access the extra parameters only. the rest are accessible.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add columns that you need to `withPivot()` method of `belongsToMany` relation:

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class)->withPivot('paid', 'transaction_id', 'amount');
}
```

2) Then access pivot columns trough `->pivot` property.

```
@foreach ($student->packages as $package)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$package->id}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->name}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->pivot->amount}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->no_hours}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->pivot->transaction_id}} </td>
        <td> {{$package->pivot->paid}} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `pivot` attribute of the model as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

For example:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

Read the linked docs, it gives a lot of details for various use cases.